# Regular Expression to replace <p> tags with line breaks

Tags: java, regex, html-parsing

I have the following HTML

```
<p>Some text <a title="link" href="http://link.com/" target="_blank">my link</a> more 
text <a title="link" href="http://link.com/" target="_blank">more link</a>.</p>
<p>Another paragraph.</p>
<p>[code:cf]</p>
<p>&lt;cfset ArrFruits = ["Orange", "Apple", "Peach", "Blueberry", </p>
<p>"Blackberry", "Strawberry", "Grape", "Mango", </p>
<p>"Clementine", "Cherry", "Plum", "Guava", </p>
<p>"Cranberry"]&gt;</p>
<p>[/code]</p>
<p>Another line</p>
<p><img src="http://image.jpg" alt="Array" />
</p>
<p>More text</p>
<p>[code:cf]</p>
<p>&lt;table border="1"&gt;</p>
<p> &lt;cfoutput&gt;</p>
<p> &lt;cfloop array="#GroupsOf(ArrFruits, 5)#" index="arrFruitsIX"&gt;</p>
<p>  &lt;tr&gt;</p>
<p> &lt;cfloop array="#arrFruitsIX#" index="arrFruit"&gt;</p>
<p>     &lt;td&gt;#arrFruit#&lt;/td&gt;</p>
<p> &lt;/cfloop&gt;</p>
<p>  &lt;/tr&gt;</p>
<p> &lt;/cfloop&gt;</p>
<p> &lt;/cfoutput&gt;</p>
<p>&lt;/table&gt;</p>
<p>[/code]</p>
<p>With an output that looks like:</p>
<p><img src="another_image.jpg" alt="" width="342" height="85" /></p>
```

What I'm trying to do, is write a regular expression that will remove all the `<p>` or `</p>`, and whenever it finds a `</p>`, it will replace it with a line-break.

So far, my pattern looks like this:

```
/\<p\>(.*?)(<\/p>)/g
```

And I'm replacing the matches with:

```
$1\n
```

It all looks good, but it's also replacing the contents inside the `[code][/code]` tags, which in this case should not replace the `<p>` tags at all, so as a result, i would lkike to get rid of the `<p>` tags, when the content **isn't** inside the `[code]` tags.

I can't ever get negation right, I know it will be something along the lines of

```
\<p\>^\[code*\](.*?)(<\/p>)
```

But obviously this doesn't work :-)

Could anyone please lend me a hand with this regex?

**BTW, I know I shouldn't be using regular expressions to parse HTML at all. I'm fully aware of that, but still, for this specific case, I'd like to use regex.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: What regex flavor are you using? Javascript? Java? .NET? PERL? Python?

Comment: "but still, for this specific case, I'd like to use regex." ... But still, I want to ride my bicycle to Antarctica.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have special knowedge about the application which generated the HTML you are venturing to parse, otherwise [you would not be even considering regular expressions for the task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348#1732454).  (Part of that is also, I assume, knowledge that `<p>` tags always appear after a newline and that `</p>` closing tags always appear before a newline.)

The above having been said, you cannot easily or efficiently achieve what you are trying to achieve with regular expressions alone (you would have to use complex nested look-behind and look-ahead assertions to validate that your `<p>...</p>` occurrence is not inside a `[code]...[/code]` block, and non-fixed-length look-behind assertions are particularly limited, and IIRC plain buggy prior to JDK1.6.)

You should first iterate over the input sequence, breaking it down into `code` and non-`code` chunks, and transferring the chunks into the output sequence either unchanged (in the case of `code` chunks) or with `<p>...</p>`-substitution applied via regex or simple string replacement (in the case of non-`code` chunks.)

Up to you if you will have to (or how you want to) deal with nested or mismatched `code` chunks.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I shouldn't be using regular
>   expressions to parse HTML at all. I'm
>   fully aware of that, but still, for
>   this specific case, I'd like to use
>   regex.

Can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: "I know I shouldn't pound nails with a screwdriver, but this time, I'd like to use a screwdriver." Just Say No!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for negative lookahead is `(?!)`.

`(?![code.*?]([^\[]|\[\/[^c]|\[\/c[^o]|\[\/co[^d]|\[\/cod[^e]|\[\/code[^\]])*)<p>.*?</p>`

Comment: This only leaves the first line of my code block with the <p> tags, everything else hasn't it, and only works for one code block on the page